# How to remove extension and force trailing slash with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, absolute-path

I managed to solve this problem by the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

In other words, not to do anything if its a directory.

Yet, my current problem is that css and the images are not loaded until I change the path to the css file and to the images to the absolute path.

Is there any other way to solve it rather then changing all the paths in all the files in the website to absolute.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are your images and CSS files in specific subdirectories or scattered around the place?

Comment: the images are at the "images" directory and the css files are at "style" directory

Answer (score 1):

Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to the first two `RewriteCond`, then images and css won't hit the rewrite, but PHP files will, and things that are not folders will also hit the rewrite